# defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null - Error including file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am new on wordpress and i am trying to merge a website with wordpress as a theme which contains its own php files and folders " forms, includes, ajax and others .. "

i am using this to define and call a path on my files

```
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS . 'home' .DS . 'sitename' . DS . 'public_html');
```

when i tried to do this in wordpress , it doesnt work , so i typed the full path like this

```
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS . 'home' .DS . 'sitename' . DS . 'public_html' . DS . 'wordpress' . DS . 'wp-content' . DS . 'themes' . DS . 'citation');
```

it works locally! .. i tried to upload it online and i changed the path to

```
    defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', 'c:' .DS . 'wamp' . DS . 'www' . DS . 'wordpress' . DS . 'wp-content' . DS . 'themes' . DS . 'citation');
```

but it doesnt work.

---

after searching i found an absolute path for wordpress folder , then i tried it locally and it works!

```
defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', ABSPATH . DS . 'wp-content' . DS . 'themes' . DS . 'citation');
```

i tried it online but it doesnt work again ..

any one can help ?

Comment: Can you give us what SITE_ROOT is ? (echo)

Comment: i am just defining the path for my website by this SITE_ROOT , so i can use it to call other folders that contains function files on my website like this ..

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT . DS . 'includes');

defined('LANG_DIR') ? NULL : define('LANG_DIR', SITE_ROOT . DS . 'languages');

require_once (LIB_PATH . DS . 'session.php');

Answer (score 0):

You may use this syntax:

```
defined("SITE_ROOT") || define("SITE_ROOT", "provide url here");
```

But this is not the solution, just a nice shortcut for defining a constant, anyways, you don't need to do this, WorrdPress has `TEMPLATEPATH`, instead and also `WordPress` provided so any helper functions for this kind of things and one of those:

```
// Prints http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/yourThrme
echo get_bloginfo('template_url');
```

Or use

```
// prints http://www.example.com/home/wp/wp-content/themes/yourThrme
bloginfo('template_url');
```

Also, worth checking these [available functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Available_Functions). Check [WordPress Integration](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) with other Website.

Comment: thank u for ur answer , this will be great if i am working on wordpress files , i am doing something like merging another Developed website and have its own includes folder to wordpress theme.

i tried what u typed but nothing changed , Thanks a lot :)

Comment: thanks for the link :) i didnt solve the problem yet but its another way for integration :)